# Azure scheduler job not running - error no route registered

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am getting below error while running Azure web job in scheduler -

**Http Action - Response from host 'site.scm.azurewebsites.net': 'NotFound' Response Headers: Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 06:11:42 GMT Set-Cookie: 
Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=site.scm.azurewebsites.net Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Body: "No route registered for '/api/triggeredwebjobs/WebsiteEnquiries/run'"**

please help me to resolve this.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Likely unrelated to scheduler, and is due to an issue on the WebJobs side. What happens if you go to site.scm.azurewebsites.net in the browser? Can you hit the `/api/triggeredwebjobs` API from there? Is your WebJob listed?

Answer (score 0):

According to exception, it seems that there is no named **WebsiteEnquiries** triggered webjobs. As David Ebbo mentioned that we could check the Webjob with kudu webapi(https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs) to list the triggered Webjob.

We also could check the WebJob from the Azure portal.

[image]